# COPY command does not ignore sequence column

Tags: postgresql, csv, import

I have a database whereas the first column is labeled as `serial not null primary key`. The table creation and automatic sequence table creation is successful. However, whenever I do:

`copy <table_name> from '/path/to/file' delimiter ',' CSV HEADER;`

PostgreSQL tries to read my first column into the serial column, which fails because my first column in my CSV file contains characters (not an integer).

How can I tell the COPY command to populate using a serial column as the first column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I determined that if I specified the header names and named my columns exactly like the header names in my CSV file, that the import worked:

```
copy <table_name>(column1, column2, etc) from '/path/to/file' delimiter ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Comment: It's the same behaviour as `INSERT`.